# Login loop Ubuntu 18.04 g_array_unref assertion 'array' failed

Tags: boot, 18.04, nvidia

I reconfigured my work space an implemented a DVI Dual Screen KVM and now I get the login screen but after authentication it fails and loops back to the login screen. I've looked at several of the other issues and tried chown user:user etc but that didn't fix it.
I looked at the log and found this line: g_array_unref assertion 'array' failed

cat /var/log/syslog

```
    :  (**) Option "fd" "75"
    :  (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
    :  (**) Option "fd" "68"
    :  (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
    :  g_array_unref: assertion 'array' failed
    :  (**) Option "fd" "73"
    :  (II) event2  - ATEN DVI DualView KVM: device removed
    :  g_array_unref: assertion 'array' failed
    :  (**) Option "fd" "66"
    :  (II) event3  - ATEN DVI DualView KVM: device removed
    :  _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
    :  _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
    :  (--) Log file renamed from "/var/log/Xorg.pid-1815.log" to "/var/log/Xorg.1.log"
    :  X.Org X Server 1.19.6
    :  Release Date: 2017-12-20
    :  X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
    :  Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-168-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
    :  Current Operating System: Linux d*** 4.15.0-91-generic #92-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 11:09:48 UTC 2020 x86_64
    :  Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-91-generic root=UUID=61b60a10-00ae-4581-b3f9-5bf705bddbfe ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
    :  Build Date: 14 November 2019  06:20:00PM
    :  xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.4 
    :  Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
    :  (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Mon         : Apr  6 12:43:06 2020
    :  (==) Using system config directory"/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
    :  (==) No Layout section.  Using thefirst Screen section.
    :  (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
    :  (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
    :  (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
    :  (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    :  #011Using a default monitor configuration.
    :  (==) Automatically adding devices
    :  (==) Automatically enabling devices
    :  (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
    :  (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
    :  (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
    :  (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
    :  #011Entry deleted from font path.
    :  (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
    :  #011Entry deleted from font path.
    :  (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
    :  #011Entry deleted from font path.
    :  (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
    :  #011Entry deleted from font path.
    :  (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
    :  #011Entry deleted from font path.
    :  (==) FontPath set to:
    :  #011/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    :  #011/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    :  #011built-ins
    :  (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    :  (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    :  #011If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
    :  (II) Loader magic: 0x55776c430020
    :  (II) Module ABI versions:
    :  #011X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
    :  #011X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
    :  #011X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
    :  #011X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
    :  (++) using VT number 2
    :  (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_3319
    :  (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
    :  (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 13 paused 0
    :  (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
    :  (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card1 226:1 fd 14 paused 0
    :  (**) OutputClass "nvidia" ModulePath extended to "/usr/lib/nvidia-340/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    :  (**) OutputClass "nvidia" ModulePath extended to "/usr/lib/nvidia-340/xorg,/usr/lib/nvidia-340/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    :  (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:0611:3842:c801 rev 162, Mem @ 0xf8000000/16777216, 0xb0000000/268435456, 0xf6000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000ac00/1 28, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
    :  (--) PCI: (0:6:0:0) 10de:0623:1b0a:9015 rev 161, Mem @ 0xfd000000/16777216, 0xd0000000/268435456, 0xfa000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000dc00/1 28, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
    :  (II) LoadModule: "glx"
    :  (II) Loading /usr/lib/nvidia-340/xorg/libglx.so
    :  (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
    :  #011compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
    :  #011Module class: X.Org Server Extension
    :  (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  340.107  Thu May 24 21:40:32 PDT 2018
    :  (II) Applying OutputClass "nvidia"to /dev/dri/card0
    :  #011loading driver: nvidia
    :  (II) Applying OutputClass "nvidia"to /dev/dri/card1
    :  #011loading driver: nvidia
    :  (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
    :  (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
    :  (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 2
    :  (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 3
    :  (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 4
    :  (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 5
    :  (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 6
    :  (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 7
    :  (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
    :  (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
    :  (II) Loading /usr/lib/nvidia-340/xorg/nvidia_drv.so
    :  (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIACorporation"
    :  #011compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
    :  #011Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    :  (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
    :  (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
    :  (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.OrgFoundation"
    :  #011compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.15
    :  #011Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    :  #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver,version 23.0
    :  (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
    :  (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
    :  (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    :  #011compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.19.6
    :  #011Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    :  #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver,version 23.0
    :  (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
    :  (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
    :  (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    :  #011compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.4.4
    :  #011Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    :  #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver,version 23.0
    :  (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
    :  (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
    :  (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    :  #011compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 2.3.4
    :  #011Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    :  #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver,version 23.0
    :  (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  340.107  Thu May 24 21:18:05 PDT 2018
    :  (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for allSupported NVIDIA GPUs
    :  (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Fri Apr 21 14:41:17 2017 -0400
    :  (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
    :  (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
    :  (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
    :  (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
    :  (II) Loading sub module "fb"
    :  (II) LoadModule: "fb"
    :  (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
    :  (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    :  #011compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
    :  #011ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
    :  (WW) Unresolved symbol: fbGetGCPrivateKey
    :  (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
    :  (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
    :  (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
    :  (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    :  #011compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
    :  #011ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
    :  (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
    :  (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
    :  (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
    :  (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
    :  (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
    :  (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
    :  (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
    :  (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
    :  (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.OrgFoundation"
    :  #011compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 0.0.2
    :  #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver,version 23.0
    :  (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
    :  (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for (null): -22
    :  (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    :  #011"Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
    :  (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
    :  (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
    :  (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
    :  (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    :  (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
    :  (II) NVIDIA(0): Display (ViewSonicVX2250 SERIES (DFP-0)) does not support
    :  (II) NVIDIA(0):     NVIDIA 3D Vision stereo.
    :  (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Found DRM driver nvidia-drm (20150116)
    :  (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce8800 GT (G92) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
    :  (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 524288 kBytes
    :  (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 62.92.24.00.01
    :  (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
    :  (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GeForce 8800 GT at PCI:1:0:0
    :  (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-0
    :  (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-1
    :  (--) NVIDIA(0):     TV-0
    :  (--) NVIDIA(0):     ViewSonic VX2250 SERIES (DFP-0) (boot, connected)
    :  (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1
    :  (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
    :  (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-1: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
    :  (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): TV-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
    :  (--) NVIDIA(0): ViewSonic VX2250 SERIES (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
    :  (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): ViewSonic VX2250 SERIES (DFP-0): 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
    :  (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
    :  (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
    :  (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
    :  (**) NVIDIA(0):     device ViewSonic VX2250 SERIES (DFP-0) (Using EDID
    :  (**) NVIDIA(0):     frequencies has been enabled on all display devices.)
    :  (==) NVIDIA(0):
    :  (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
    :  (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
    :  (==) NVIDIA(0):
    :  (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
    :  (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-0:nvidia-auto-select"
    :  (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1920 x 1080
    :  (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (101, 101); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
    :  (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
    :  (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
    :  (II) Unloading fbdev
    :  (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
    :  (II) Unloading fbdevhw
    :  (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
    :  (II) Unloading vesa
    :  (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
    :  (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-1): Failed to determine chip graphics capabilities
    :  (II) NVIDIA(GPU-1): Deleting GPU-1
    :  (II) NVIDIA: Using 768.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory access.
    :  (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to create synchronization event
    :  (EE) NVIDIA(0):  *** Aborting ***
    :  (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to allocate2D objects
    :  (EE) NVIDIA(0):  *** Aborting ***
    :  (EE)
    :  Fatal server error:
    :  (EE) AddScreen/ScreenInit failed for driver 0
    :  (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
    :  Unable to run X server
    : Apr  6 12:43:06 d*****-Machine gdm3: GdmDisplay: display lasted 0.837912 seconds
    : Apr  6 12:43:06 d*****-Machine gdm3: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: maximum number of X display failures reached check X server log for errors
    :  (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:64
    :  (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 226:0
    :  (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 226:1
    :  (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DFP-0:nvidia-auto-select"
    :  acpid: client 1176[0:0] has disconnected
    :  acpid: client connected from 1176[0:0]
    :  acpid: 1 client rule loaded
    :  (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (ViewSonic VX2250 SERIES (DFP-0)) does not support
    :  (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     NVIDIA 3D Vision stereo.
    :  (II) event0  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
    :  (II) event0  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
    :  (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:65
    :  (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
    :  (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
    :  (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:67
    :  (II) event3  - ATEN DVI DualView KVM: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
    :  (II) event3  - ATEN DVI DualView KVM: device is a pointer
    :  (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:66
    :  (II) event2  - ATEN DVI DualView KVM: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
    :  (II) event2  - ATEN DVI DualView KVM: device is a keyboard
    :  gnome-shell[1211]: g_array_unref: assertion 'array' failed
```

Answer (score 0):

ran sudo apt-get upgrade and the subsequent restart and everything magically started working